# Group URLs based on common element

Tags: sql, regex, looker-studio

I have a URL field in my dataset, and I want to replace any URLs that look like this:

```
/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}GBBLADV8
/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}GBAPTX8E
/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}IEWWG9HG
/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}IEY2DCPC
```

and so on,

With this:
/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}

Is there a way to do this in Looker Studio?

It's worth noting that the ID at the end of these URLs always starts with either GB or IE.

I've tried using REGEXP_CONTAINS in a CASE statement, but it doesn't seem to recognise % operators because it didn't change anything.

```
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, "/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}GB%") 
    OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, "/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}IE%") 
    THEN "/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}"
  ELSE url
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you try:*

```js
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, "}(?:GB|IE)")
    THEN "/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}"
    ELSE url
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have this old booking ref and number id in another column so you may just update the column with these values "/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}"

Comment: I want to group all occurrences of "/manage/{old_booking_ref}{number_id}" together, so I don't want to use the individual number ids or old booking refs. I just want to remove the ID at the end of these URLs.

Comment: OK, then I am not getting the problem you are having.